# Password protect a SQLite database with SQLite-Net Extensions

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, sqlite-net-extensions

I want to password protect a SQLite database (not fully encrypt it) in a Xamarin project that uses MVVMCross and SQLite-Net Extensions. Even if the default SQLite Nuget seems to have a password option on creating the database connection, the SQLite-Net Extension doesn't. Am I missing something? Is it an easier way to accomplish this than writing custom code on each platform for handling the connection? Thanks!